# Solving an equation and finding a couple of results given that they are integer

Tags: equation-solving

My problem is to find all solutions to an equation with 2 variables between two values that define the range of my search.
e.g., $(x+y-y²)/(1-y-x²)=0$ with solutions ${x,y} \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following might be of use:

```
Reduce[x + y == y^2 && x^2 + y != 1, {x, y}, Integers]
```

To ease things, we consider the numerator and denominator separately. Here, we are asking *Mathematica* for conditions on integer `x` and `y` such that the numerator is zero, and the denominator isn't.

```
Solve[x + y == y^2 && x^2 + y != 1, {x, y}, Integers]
```

is useful as well.

---

If you need examples, you can use

```
FindInstance[x + y == y^2 && x^2 + y != 1, {x, y}, Integers, 10]
```

Change `10` to the number of examples you wish to generate.

Comment: thanks the tip of separating numerator and denominator is great ;)

Comment: and for the FindInstance 10 that's what I needed!

Answer (score 7):

You can obtain all integer solutions with [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html):

```
Reduce[(x + y - y^2)/(1 - y - x^2) == 0, {x, y}, Integers]
```

which gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you also want to restrict to solutions satisfying $x<15$ and $y<42$ then this works

```
Reduce[(x + y - y^2)/(1 - y - x^2) == 0 && x < 15 && x < 42, {x,y}, Integers]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: ok thanks and if I want to condition it so that x and y are between [O,1]  (how to condition the solving process?)

Comment: you can do that in a way analogous to the second example I gave

Comment: yep thanks Acl ^^